# Changing colors from dataframe from a second dataframe

Tags: r

I am attempting to change the color of the top 6 values for each variable in data. I have the colors (top.n.color) and the top 6 values for each variable (top.n), but I am having trouble making the color replacement and then adding the new colors of top.n back into data. How would I go about this?

```
data <- structure(list(Sample.Number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                                         11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
                                         8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                         5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 
                                         2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
                                         20), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                     3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                     4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Static", "D10 FB", "D12 FB", 
                                                                                                             "D14 FB"), class = "factor"), value = c(9.61, 7, 6.59, 6.58, 
                                                                                                                                                     6, 5.93, 57.5, 45.5, 39.5, 39, 22.5, 21.5, 128.5, 78.5, 71.5, 
                                                                                                                                                     49, 40.5, 40, 36, 35, 390, 478, 298, 524, 474, 406, 478, 1043, 
                                                                                                                                                     448, 454, 519, 710, 838, 1481, 737, 305, 668, 1096, 340, 152, 
                                                                                                                                                     735, 760, 439, 882, 742, 730, 5923, 3697, 806, 927, 1726, 1436, 
                                                                                                                                                     593, 3545, 1669, 814, 1733, 2333, 819, 260, 586, 854, 506, 1067, 
                                                                                                                                                     747, 781, 1557, 3807, 1063, 1795, 1534, 2761, 666, 2887, 1737, 
                                                                                                                                                     1044, 2211, 2544, 1181, 322), color = c("black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black"
                                                                                                                                                     )), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = "data.frame")

c25 <- c("dodgerblue2", "#E31A1C", "green4", "#6A3D9A", "#FF7F00", "black", "gold1", "skyblue2", "#FB9A99", 
         "palegreen2", "#CAB2D6", "#FDBF6F", "gray70", "khaki2", "maroon", "orchid1", "deeppink1", "blue1", 
         "steelblue4", "darkturquoise", "green1", "yellow4", "yellow3", "darkorange4", "brown")

top.n <- data %>% group_by(variable) %>% top_n(6, value)
top.n.color <- c25[1:length(unique(top.n$Sample.Number))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some part of your code, this should solve the issue:

```
library(dplyr)
#Assign color
top.n <- data %>% group_by(variable) %>% top_n(6, value)
top.n.color <- top.n[!duplicated(top.n$Sample.Number),]
top.n.color$newcolor <- c25[1:dim(top.n.color)[1]]
#Merge data
data %>% left_join(top.n.color %>% ungroup() %>% select(c(1,5))) -> data2
#Create final color
data2 %>% mutate(FinalColor=ifelse(is.na(newcolor),color,newcolor)) -> data2
```

Then, some result rows (`FinalColor` is the final variable with colors):

```
   Sample.Number variable value color    newcolor  FinalColor
1              1   Static  9.61 black        <NA>       black
2              2   Static  7.00 black        <NA>       black
3              3   Static  6.59 black        <NA>       black
4              4   Static  6.58 black        <NA>       black
5              5   Static  6.00 black        <NA>       black
6              6   Static  5.93 black        <NA>       black
7              7   Static 57.50 black dodgerblue2 dodgerblue2
8              8   Static 45.50 black     #E31A1C     #E31A1C
9              9   Static 39.50 black        <NA>       black
10            10   Static 39.00 black     #CAB2D6     #CAB2D6
```

Comment: There is an error with the #Merge data code "Error in UseMethod("left_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "function""

Comment: @user13589693 Try starting a new session on `R`, it looks like a conflict with other method. I ran again on a new session and worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user13589693 Great, I hope this helped!